# Using Boost Graph library to find all paths

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I have a DAG, and I need to be able to find all possible paths of a certain length within a region.  For instance, I want to find all paths that contain at least 3 vertices but no more than 7.  My first thought was to find an algorithm that finds all path, then just weed them out.

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: I don't know the details of boost-graph, but depending on your graph size, doing a depth-limited breadth-first search from your starting point may be *much* faster than enumerating over the whole graph.

Answer (score 3):

Enumerating all paths of length K is in general O(2^K), so I think the suggestion above not to enumerate all possible paths is good.  For example:

[image: a graph]

Let's say all the edges in this graph are directed from left to right (so this is a DAG). Then there are 2^3 paths from the leftmost to the rightmost node (i.e. 2^3 paths of length 6) since for each of the 3 'diamonds' you can choose to take the above or below path (so we're looking at all the permutations of three binary choices).  You can extend the graph following the pattern (by tacking on diamonds) and for K diamonds there will be 2^K paths of length 2K.

So you'll probably want to enumerate only the paths you have to (especially if they are short like in your example).

I think the above suggestion to use breadth first search would work for enumerating all paths, but for larger cases the space requirement would be 2^K (when looking for all paths of length K or less); I say this because you'll have to remember all the paths of length n-1 to find all paths of length n.  Depth first search (or rather a modified version of it) would work as well:

```
DFS(int maxLen, Node node):
    list<Node> path
    path.add(node)
    DFS_Helper(maxLen, path)

DFS_Helper(int maxLen, list<Node> path):
    print(path)
    if (path.size() >= maxLen)
        return
    set<Node> targets = graph.getNodesPointedToBy(path.last())
    for Node target in targets:
        path.append(target)
        DFS(maxLen, path)
        path.removeLastNode()
```

the space usage is O(|V|) (any vertex in V the set of vertices can appear in the 'targets' set of at most one recursive call since the graph is acyclic).  Note that this still will have O(2^k) runtime (unavoidable as discussed above) and I'm guessing that because of that boost won't have a ready made algorithm for you to do this (which is why I included some pseudocode above).  This doesn't include a lower bound but that shouldn't be too bad to include.

EDIT: I originally argued that the space usage of DFS was O(K) where K was the max path length.  This was incorrect and lower than the actual space usage, since I neglected to include the space used by the 'targets' set in each recursive call to DFS_Helper.  The space usage is still significantly less than for BFS.